# how to add phtml file in magento 1 homepage?

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml

Which is the quickiest way to add/call a phtml file in homepage (only)
in magento 1 (custom theme) ?

I am not sure about magento 1, so any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. From cms page

   `{{block type="core/template" template="brand/brand.phtml"}}`

in which `brand/brand.phtml` is the path inside templates folder of you theme e.g `app/design/frontend/active_theme/default/templates/brand/brand.phtml`

2. Call another phtml from one phtml

   `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('brand/brand.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>`

Both ways are correct and efficient in magento.